# Speech Synthesis browser APIs do not work in Chromium nor Firefox

Tags: browser, manjaro, text-to-speech

Speech Synthesis API, tested using [demo here](http://mdn.github.io/web-speech-api/speak-easy-synthesis/), does not work for me on Manjaro Linux KDE neither in Firefox nor Chromium. Friend tested the same demo on Linux Mint xfce and it works for him in Firefox.

On my machine `speechSynthesis.getVoices()` executed in dev console returns an empty array. Do I maybe miss some packages in my system?

Answer (score 3):

You can install [`espeak`](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/)

```
$ sudo <package manager install> espeak
```

At Chromium launch with [`--enable-speech-dispatcher`](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#enable-speech-dispatcher) flag and utilize [`onvoiceschanged`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/onvoiceschanged) event

```
window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = e => {
  const voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
  console.log(voices);
}
window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
```